# Is there any way to generate a dynamic pdf and download it, without rendering it using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pdfrenderer

I am trying to generate a dynamic pdf, with some layout and it works fine, and I can download it too. But what I want is to download it without rendering it front-end. I am using `@react-pdf/renderer` for the same.

I tried using css property like `display:"none"` to accoplish it, but nothing seemed working. Is there any way make it work.

Note: I am trying to achieve it from front-end itself.

Comment: How would you download a document that is not yet created/rendered?

Comment: @SimonWeber, trying to figure out a way that won't let the document render on the client side, somehow gets created, if it's possible.

Comment: I don't use this, but looking at the source there is a `toBlob` method on the `pdf` export,..  So you should be able to do -> `pdf(<Document>....</Document>).toBlob()`, it will return a Promise that returns a Blob, that you can then use with `URL.createObjectURL` for downloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the answer for future reference,

This could be done with the `pdf()` method provided by `@react-pdf/renderer`.

```js
  const downloadPdf = async () => {
    const fileName = 'test.pdf';
    const blob = await pdf(<YourDocument />).toBlob();
    saveAs(blob, fileName);
  };
```

For more details refer to this [discussion](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/discussions/2352#discussioncomment-6343721)